# htaccess protect directory with redirecting by ip

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

here my htaccess files

/.htaccess

```
<IfModule autoindex>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

/secret/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=98.81.105.12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !%{HTTP_HOST}/secret/$
RewriteRule .* %{HTTP_HOST} [R=302,L]
```

So, the target is to protect https://example.com/secret/ with IP filter with redirecting to https://example.com or even better to show 404 error "Not found"
My solution does not work. Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final RewriteRule would be better off redirecting to "/" than to %{HTTP_HOST}. The value of that variable has no scheme/port/URL so it's not really expected to be the target of a redirect.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense :)
but now the problem is, I will be redirected to the homepage despite the correct IP 
Something's wrong with this line
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !%{HTTP_HOST}/secret/$`

Comment: Very strange behavior, even without `%{HTTP_HOST}` it does not work.
Any idea?

Comment: need more than "does not work". What's the verbatim request, response, and what response did you want?

Comment: ok it works now. The problem was a PHP script :rolleyes:
thanks